# Android device control multiple BLE device Issue

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use Android device to control multiple BLE devices. Each connection use different BluetoothGatt to handle BLE operation. It works fine, but when I want to disconnect the device, I called `bluetoothgatt.disconnect();` and `onConnectionStateChange` callback actually call `BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED`, but the device is still in Connected state. I still can send or receive data. Why?

Comment: did you call `disconnect()` method on correct `bluetoothgatt` object ?

Comment: Yes, I related different bluetoothgatt for each  devices. Actually ,when i connect four devices. Only last device could disconnect successfully .Why?

Comment: Instead making different BluetoothGatt , why not you use the same BluetoothGatt but with different services for each connection?